# Configuring Jenkins with SSH jump hosts

Tags: jenkins, ssh, proxy, jenkins-plugins

How do I configure SSH connections in jenkins, when I have an intermediate bastion with its own user and key like this:

```
Host jump
  User user1
  HostName jumpdns
  IdentityFile /Users/myname/.ssh/jumpkey.pem

Host server
  User user2
  HostName serverdns
  IdentityFile /Users/myname/.ssh/serverkey.pem
  ForwardAgent yes
  ProxyJump jump
```

This works on cli as `ssh server`. But I dont know how to encode that into my jenkins that is running locally in my laptop from within my user and not as a separate jenkins user ie. `JENKINS_HOME=/Users/myname/.jenkins`

I looked into [Publish over SSH](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) plugin and it does provide for a jumpdns option but not jump's own user and key. And it seems like others have been been [looking](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/JIRA-JENKINS-37310-Support-Jump-Hosts-via-SSH-Tunnel-td4833489.html) for it without a solution.

What is the best way to configure Jenkins for my SSH setup?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on jenkins version: 2.303.2. This is the latest version as of now.

If your master has a SSH version(OpenSSH_7.4p1 for example) which supports jump host option then you can try this:

-Select Launch method as 'Launch agent via execution via execution of command on controller'

-Launch command: ssh -tt -J user@jump_host_name user@destination_host

https://www.tecmint.com/access-linux-server-using-a-jump-host/